# mysql query search with "If" statement

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

So, I have following php query:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cat_result) ; ++$i) {          
    $query_p    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = %d"; 
    $results[]  = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query_p, $cat_result[$i]));            
}
```

The search relies on `$cat_result` which contains numerous numbers.

For example, let say `$cat_result` contains the following number: '1,3,5,21,35`

Using these 5 numbers, the query will look for the db info.

However, there are scenarios where some number (for example, "21") do not exist in the db.

Then, I get `PHP NOTICE: trying to get property of non-object`.

How do I write "if" statement so that if the `id` (in this case "21") does not exist, then it simply ignores the query? (It is hard to explain what I mean by "ignore". I still want the query to do the search but if it does not find what it is looking for, then simply ignore the error).

Comment: Why not just say:   `SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id in ( $cat_result );`

Comment: @Matt `IFNULL` doesn't help if no row matches.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh, may have been mistaken then.

Comment: Ah, @Barmar Didn't think of that. Thanks for pointing out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($cat_result) ; ++$i) {          
    $query_p    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id = %d"; 
    $row = $wpdb->get_row($wpdb->prepare($query_p, $cat_result[$i]));
    if ($row) {
        $results[]  = $row;
    }    
}
```

I don't know WordPress, but I suspect `get_row` returns `false` when there are no more rows of results. Your code was putting `false` into `$results` when that happened, and later code was then trying to use that as an object.

Answer (score 3):

I think you should restructure your query.  That way, as long as your data is sanitized (to prevent injection as im not sure if it comes from the user or not), you can just do the following:

```
$cat_result = implode(",", $cat_result);
$query_p    = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE id in ( $cat_result )";
$rslt       = $wpdb->get_results($query_p);
// loop result
```

That way, it will fetch you all in that list.

Comment: `$cat_result` is an array, not a string.

Comment: You need to use `implode(', ', $cat_result)`.

Comment: Use `$cat_result = implode(",", $cat_result); `

Comment: Plus, plz don't use `mysql_query` :). It's using a wordpress query, plus `mysql_*` is depreciated

Comment: adjusted.  I was not 100% sure of the datastructure that was `$cat_result` as it looked like a comma delimited string. `1,2,3,4` but... i guess it was an array

Comment: @Matt Well, dang, all my code is out of date.  I should update